# How would I join two rotation vectors in geometry nodes?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, mathematics, instances, vector

I've been stuck on this for quite a while now, I'm trying to combine Rotation 1 with Rotation 2 and it's been doing my head in.

I'm trying to instance 5 or so objects and rotate them away from select objects. I've done that successfully, but I wanted to also randomly rotate all objects on the z axis and a small amount on x and y **except** for the ones rotated away from the objects.

I'm able to either rotate all objects randomly or rotate away from an object, the issue is combining the two.

Any help is tons appreciated!

Using blender 3.0.0

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXmqwmEtR8dWyr3o-RdSCbq8HX58FRCF/view?usp=sharing)

Nodes:
[image: Nodes]

First Rotation:
[image: one]

Second Rotation:

[image: Two]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understood you right, you wanna do this:

[image]

as you can see by changing the seed in the node tree i only randomize the instances which are not near the spheres.

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that worked great, thanks man!

Comment: Thank you very much! You are welcome!